# Create links between ESDoc functions/classes and manual pages and vica-versa

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation, esdoc

I'm new to [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org) but have many years JSDoc experience.

The nearest equivalent to JSDoc's *Tutorials* features is ESDoc's *Manual* feature. It lets you write stand-alone markdown documentation that gets incorporated into the final built documentation.

I have two problems:

1. In the description of a function or class, how do I link to a section within the manual? In JSDoc the @tutorial tag did that, but it doesn't exist in ESDoc, and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent @manual tag.
2. In a manual page, how do I link back to the documentation for a function/class? In JSDoc I could use the @link tag, but that is not working in ESDoc manual pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@see` according the the docs [here](https://esdoc.org/manual/tags.html#-link)